# Not possible to use HAVING clause in transform sql statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Is it possible to use the HAVING clause with the transform statement in MS Access 2010?
I keep getting “Syntax error in transform statement”

My sql is

```
TRANSFORM FIRST(appointment_date) As FirstOfappointment_date
SELECT rank, complete_name
FROM appointment_overview
WHERE status IS NULL OR status <> ‘Deleted’
GROUP BY rank, complete_name
HAVING COUNT(appointment_id) < 2
PIVOT type;
```

I tried testing the select statement by itself and it works fine

Is what I’m trying to do not supported by access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `Having` is not available when executing a `Pivot`.

A possible workaround is to use a subquery, and move your `Having` clause to the `Where` clause:

```sql
TRANSFORM FIRST(appointment_date) As FirstOfappointment_date
SELECT rank, complete_name
FROM appointment_overview a
WHERE (status IS NULL OR status <> 'Deleted')
AND (SELECT Count(s.appointment_id) FROM appointment_overview s WHERE (status IS NULL OR status <> 'Deleted') AND s.rank = a.rank AND s.complete_name = a.complete_name) = 2
GROUP BY rank, complete_name
PIVOT type;
```

Note that this may have a substantial impact on performance.

Comment: Noted. Thank you so much!